# Unable to fully disable UAC in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, administrator, uac

I have problem with fully disable UAC (User Account Control) in Windows 8. I've never had such problems in Windows Vista, or Windows 7 - just have to disable UAC in Control Panel, reboot, and that's it.

Ok, step by step:

I've just make one account, during installation - account "Namek".
In "Control Panel -> Accounts" I see only one account "Namek", and next to the avatar picture, it's:

```
Namek
Local Account
Administrator
```

Using:

```
cmd -> net users
```

there are:

```
Administrator   Guest   Namek
```

using:

```
cmd -> net users Administrator
```

and:

```
cmd -> net users Namek
```

the only difference are:
`Comment` - in Administrator it's `built-in`, in Namek it's empty
`Account active` - Administrator `no`, Namek `yes`
`Password required` - Administrator `yes`, Namek `no` (because during Windows 8 installation I left password empty).

So I started with:

```
Control Panel -> Accounts -> Family Safety section
```

and set slider to value:

```
Never notify
```

reboot, and now, I've problem when for example I try to save anything, using Paint, directly on C:\ drive.
It says:

```
You don't have permission to save in this location.
Contact the administrator to obtain permission.
Would you like to save in the My Pictures folder instead?
```

---

Ok, I've read some tutorials on the Internet, and I see that the case isn't as easy as in Windows Vista, or Windows 7 -> just disable UAC in Control Panel... so next step:

In `gpedit.msc`, I have already set:

```
Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Security Options ---> User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode
```

At value:

```
Elevate without prompting
```

So i didn't have to changed it.

---

In `regedit`:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

At value:

```
EnableLUA
```

I had default `1`, so I set it to `0`.
but again nothing has changed.

---

On another Windows 8 (on VirtualBox) I've try solution, to acti ve built-in Administrator account, typig:
"cmd -> net user administrator /active:yes"
and now after start Windows 8 I can login to Administrator account, and now I've got FULLY permissions, but when I'm logout, and login on normal account, with 'administrator' permissions (which I created during installation), I've again problem when for example I try to save anything, using Paint, directly on C:\ drive.
It says:
"You don't have permission...blabla"

It's annoying, that I always have to right click some program, and click `Run as administrator`.
I do not want to activate in my normal system `Administrator` account (by `net user administrator /active:yes`), and work on it, because on `Namek` account, I've already set a lot of things...
Any help, please :(?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, now I try to check everything again, and I see, that in:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`

At:

```
Ena‌​bleLUA
```

value didn't change correctly. It's still `1`. So I again try to set this value to `0`, reboot, and now it's `0`, and I have fully administrator permission :). It can be useful for someone :).

PS: You can also try to `Run as administrator`.

Comment: But have in mind that after changing this in registry, you can not use Microsoft Store, and some apps can not start from start panel.